# Howto cleanup location listeners in activities properly

Tags: android, instances, locationlistener

I have an Activity that implements LocationListener.

```
public class MyActivity extends MapActivity  implements LocationListener
```

In my activity, I register a locationlistener in the onCreate()

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, minTime, distance, this);
```

In the onDestroy method, I'm removing the registration for my locationlistener.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Utils.addDebugMsg(this,"onDestroy");
    lm.removeUpdates(this);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

In my application, I can change the minTime and distance, so I re-initialize my listener like this :

```
private void initializeGpsListener() {
    lm.removeUpdates(this);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, minTime, distance, this);
}
```

For debugging purposes, I write something to the screen whenever a provider is enabled (in this case GPS).

```
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Utils.addDebugMsg(this,"onProviderEnabled : " + provider);
    }
```

What I noticed is that sometimes, multiple instances of my activity (or locationlistener) are "kept around". Each time I turn the GPS provider on, instead of seeing 1 statement "onProviderEnabled : GPS", I see several different instances of my Activity printing this line (all at the same time).

How do I clean up these listeners ( = my activities), and make sure that only 1 remains active throughout the application.

Comment: Just thought I'd mention I resolved the issue.

Comment: The Activity implemented OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener. During onCreate, the activity was registered as a PreferenceChangelistener, but not unregistered in the onDestroy(). As such, even after the activity was destroyed, there was still a reference to the activity, causing the duplicate messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Activity implemented OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.

During onCreate, the activity was registered as a PreferenceChangelistener, but not unregistered in the onDestroy().

As such, even after the activity was destroyed, there was still a reference to the activity, causing the duplicate messages.